# Why does Spark Streaming's Kafka Direct Stream throw "EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel"?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am getting this error, when i try to consume `Kafka Topic using Spark Streaming`.

Our cluster is secured using Kerberos authentication.

Is it something we need to set it like `Kerberos authentication` details in the Kafka Params.

**Sample Code:**

```
val topicsSet = "topic".split(",").toSet
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> "1.2.3.4:6667")
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
    val lines = messages.map(_._2)
    lines.foreachRDD( rdd => rdd.foreach { x => println(x) })
```

The kafka version in the cluster is `0.9.0.1`

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**error log:**

```
INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
    at com.scb.upv.TestSparkStreamingConsumer$delayedInit$body.apply(TestSparkStreamingConsumer.scala:19)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at com.scb.upv.TestSparkStreamingConsumer$.main(TestSparkStreamingConsumer.scala:11)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using Spark Integration for Kafka 0.8. What's the version of Spark? Is the address of the Kafka broker `1.2.3.4:6667` correct? Can you produce and consume messages using `kafka-console-producer` or `kafka-console-consumer`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: i am using the versions 1.6.1, updated my question with all dependencies. Yes i can produce and consume message, but its a secured cluster, so i have to use `security-protocol`, when i consume/publish message using console.

Comment: What about logs on the broker side when Spark tries to connect? I've never worked with secured Kafka brokers so might not be able to help...much. In the meantime, can you check if Spark 2.0.2 (just released) changes anything?

Comment: @Shankar Did u fixed the issue? I am also facing it. Any insight would be helpful

Comment: @Justin: Is your cluster kerborized? if yes, you need to pass the `SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG` value also in the kafka params..

Comment: @Shankar yes its a kerborized cluster. "security.protocol" -> "SASL_SSL" in kafkaparams . But still no luck , am using spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 1.6.1 version. Is there any issues with that?

Comment: @Justin: we are using SASL_PLAINTEXT and its working fine. also what distribution you are using, if you are using HDP or Cloudera, make sure you are using the jars from their Repository, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Shankar I am using cludera distribution. now i am getting the error like this `17/02/08 23:40:26 WARN utils.VerifiableProperties: Property security.protocol is not valid
17/02/08 23:40:26 INFO utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to
17/02/08 23:40:26 INFO consumer.SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to error:
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:99)
` Any idea what might be the reason?